# reactjs/material-ui app is whooping 917kb in production build! What do I do to decrease size?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react: 15.4.0, material-ui: 0.16.4, react-tap-event-plugin: 2.0.1 and my app has some good amount of workflows built into it. While I was getting ready for production, I see that the app is consuming 917kb in production build and app is slugish as well in terms of ui transitions. I am not sure if both these things are related or not.

I have followed almost all suggestions from different blog posts to reduce the size of the bundle but nothing helps.

Then I read some article that material-ui is heavy and can consumed a lot of space in the app so wanted to check on this possibility as well.

My dependencies in package.json looks like below and I use both create-react-app and an independent webpack setup simultaneously.

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-loader": "6.2.9",
  "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.19.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "6.16.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.16.0",
  "babel-register": "6.18.0",
  "babel-runtime": "6.20.0",
  "body-parser": "1.15.2",
  "concurrently": "3.1.0",
  "express": "4.14.0",
  "formsy-material-ui": "0.5.3",
  "formsy-react": "0.18.1",
  "https": "1.0.0",
  "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
  "localforage": "1.4.3",
  "material-ui": "0.16.6",
  "nedb": "1.8.0",
  "pako": "1.0.4",
  "peer": "0.2.8",
  "peerjs": "0.3.14",
  "pushstate-server": "2.1.0",
  "qrcode.react": "0.6.1",
  "react": "^15.4.1",
  "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
  "react-grid-layout": "0.13.9",
  "react-motion": "0.4.7",
  "react-notification-system": "0.2.11",
  "react-redux": "4.4.6",
  "react-router": "3.0.0",
  "react-swipeable-views": "0.9.1",
  "react-tap-event-plugin": "2.0.1",
  "redux": "3.6.0",
  "redux-promise-middleware": "4.2.0",
  "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
  "redux-undo": "0.6.1",
  "secrets.js-grempe": "1.1.0",
  "uuid": "3.0.1"
}
```

My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'js/bundle': './src/index.js',
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      output: {
        comments: false
      },
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true
      }
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add what package you're using to build your application? Grunt, gulp, webpack, or something different?

Comment: Updated the original post. I use create-react-app and do "npm run build" to create prod builds. Also I have used webpack independently to create production build. In both cases, build sizes are same i.e. 917kb.

Comment: Start with separating your dependencies into 'dependencies' and 'dev-dependencies'. The first is packages used during runtime, while the second is packages only used during development/build. It wont reduce the bundle size, but it'll be easier for you to get an overview of which packages goes into your bundle. I suggest you to separate your bundle into 'app' and 'vendor'. Since the 'vender' bundle should change less frequently than 'app', most of the time the browser cache will take care of it.

Comment: I don't know it it'll work with material-ui (I use materialize and create my own components) but you could look into using something like `PurifyCSSPlugin`. It traverses the paths you input and removes any css that isn't used by your app. If configured correctly, it can significantly reduce the size of your stylesheets. Other than that, you should check your react components, making sure only to import the things you really need. For bundling using webpack I highly recommend the tutorial [developing with webpack](http://survivejs.com/webpack/developing-with-webpack/)

Comment: Thanks @NikolajDamLarsen.I am actually also trying to see how react-toolbox weighs compared to material-ui. If its better both in terms of performance and size then I will just move towards using it.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen,

Btw, I was trying out `PurifyCSSPlugin` but it looks like it won't be able to remove inlined css like `material-ui` uses. Since I am new to this part of the world, so I might be missing something as well.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. It's hard to determine whether it's possible to reduce it more without having the code in front of me. But creating your bundles in such as way, that the browser cache will take care of most of the load, you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are not using named imports on all of material-ui... For example, for a `RaisedButton`, use this:

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
```

and not this:

```
import { RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';
```

The latter would import virtually all of material-ui, even if you only used that `RaisedButton` (575K vs. 192K, using your above config in a bare-bones app)

This is especially true for svg-icons. Never do this:

```
// Import ALL of the svg-icons, but only use ToggleStar (doh!)
import { ToggleStar } from 'material-ui/svg-icons'; // <- 781K bundle.js
```

For the named imports of `Card`/`CardHeader`, etc, `List`/`ListItem`, the difference is less drastic but you can still shave off 1K-5K here and there if you aren't using all of the "sub" components:

```
// Commented-out named import below produces slightly bigger code
// import { Card, CardMedia, CardTitle, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Card from 'material-ui/Card/Card';
import CardMedia from 'material-ui/Card/CardMedia';
import CardTitle from 'material-ui/Card/CardTitle';
import CardText from 'material-ui/Card/CardText';

// Commented-out named import below produces slightly bigger code
// import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui/List';
import List from 'material-ui/List/List';
import ListItem from 'material-ui/List/ListItem';
```

Comment: I am already doing this for all the material-ui/redux/react-redux components. After your comment, I also modified my use of List/ListItem/Card* components to separate files which till now I was taking from 'material-ui/List' etc. Still not much gain.